# Create container from local file

Tags: docker

I have a file called `Dockerfile` which contains a Docker configuration.

If I try to build a container from the file:

`docker build Dockerfile`

I get:

```
unable to prepare context: context must be a directory: C:\Path\To\Dockerfile
```

So how can I create a Docker container from a local configuration file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/ the parameter to `docker build` is not the Dockerfile, but a directory or URL containing the Dockerfile. So your command should rather be

```
docker build .
```

or even better, considering docker defaults to the current dir:

```
docker build
```

---

If your Dockerfile happens do be named differently (it really shouldn't), you can tell docker to use it by passing it to the `-f` or  `--file` option:

```
docker build -f MyDockerfile
```